# RestKit 0.20 - Expected content type (null)

Tags: restkit

Restkit 0.20

Does anyone know why am I getting this output on every call? Any suggestions on tracking it down? I can see the json payload in the debug output.

```
error=Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type (null), got application/json" UserInfo=0x9187fe0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={
```

The call I am making is

```
[manager getObjectsAtPath:@"/customers" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
        NSLog(@"Loaded customers: %@", statuses);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Customer Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

and my mapping code is

```
@interface DataCustomers : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* customerid;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* firstname;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* lastname;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* email;

@end



RKObjectMapping *map = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DataCustomers class]];
    [map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id" : @"customerid",
     @"firstname" : @"firstname",
     @"lastname" : @"lastname",
     @"email" : @"email"}];

[manager addResponseDescriptor: [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:map
                                                                            pathPattern:@"/customers"
                                                                                keyPath:@"customers"
                                                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

Comment: Seems to have been a library conflict somewhere. The exact same code does not have this error in a new project. Very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some weird library conflict happening that completely confused AFNetwork.

In addition to removing that problem, I added nil to the pathPattern.

Answer (score 2):

Are you properly setting your willingness to handle the content type?

Try adding this to your AppDelegate:

```
#import "RKMIMETypeSerialization.h"
#import "RKNSJSONSerialization.h"

[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: That had nothing to do with it. I had some library conflict that was occurring that had badly messed with AFNetwork. In addition, I replaced the pathPattern with nil.

Comment: Interesting. You can add an answer to this question of your own and accept it as the solution by the way.